# Craslytics deobfuscation stopped working after Firebase integration

Tags: android, firebase, crashlytics, crashlytics-android

I have Craslytics integrated in an app for long time. I'm using Proguard to obfuscate the code. Everything was working fine, I was getting my crash reports deobfuscated without problems.

Last week, I enabled the integration of Craslytics in Firebase and since then the crash reports are not being deobfuscated, neither in Crashlytics nor Firebase (I do get the crash reports in both places).

I'm using `crashlytics:2.8.0` in production (I'll update to `crashlytics:2.9.1` in next week's release). And I have all Proguard rules indicated in the docs ([Configure ProGuard and DexGuard](https://docs.fabric.io/android/crashlytics/dex-and-proguard.html)).

I've noticed that the [release notes](https://docs.fabric.io/android/changelog.html#crashlytics) from `crashlytics:2.9.0` say:

> App teams who use both Fabric and Firebase can now link their apps and use Crashlytics within the Firebase console (requires Firebase Core, version 11.4.2+ recommended).

Does that means that I shouldn't have linked Crashlytics with Firebase before updating to `crashlytics:2.9.1`? Can that be the source of the problem?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: About 10 lines up from the bottom of my build log, I see `:app:crashlyticsUploadDeobsRelease`.  Do you see that in your build log?  If not, can you update your post to include the `release` block of your build.gradle file?

Comment: I found that the upload of the mapping data was not occurring when I used the `postprocessing` block to configure my release.  Another developer [noted the same problem here](https://github.com/SUPERCILEX/Robot-Scouter/blob/master/app/build.gradle#L52-L66).

Comment: Hi Bob, thanks for your answer. I see both task in my logs `:app:crashlyticsStoreDeobsProdRelease` and
`:app:crashlyticsUploadDeobsProdRelease`. And I'm not using `postprocessing` block. It was working fine two weeks ago and I haven't done any new release since then..

Comment: Suggest you contact [Firebase Support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/).

Comment: I think I'll wait until next week when I release the new version of the app with `crashlytics:2.9.1`. If the problem persist I'll contact them. Thank you for your help!

Comment: This is happening to me as well, the difference is that in firebase it does get deobfuscate and in Crashlytics doesn't deobfuscate code.

Comment: Updating to the latest version solved my problem finally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After updating Crashlytics from `2.8.0` to `2.9.1` I started to get deobfuscated crash reports again in both Crashlytics and Firebase.